# How to correct uneven sampling distribution when calculating the mean?

Tags: sampling, error, mean

Suppose I have a function `f`, and I want to sample it at 100 points in the interval `[0, 100]`. For some reason (that seemed smart to me at the time), I decided to not sample at equidistant intervals, but rather use the following function to determine the sample points:

```
log2(x)*(100/log2(100))
```

This gives me a sequence of sample points that becomes denser as it approaches 100. The problem is, that now I need to calculate the mean over the values I have sampled, but due to the bad sampling that would be heavily biased. I cannot resample the data, this would take way too long (several days), and I am on a very tight schedule. So, the solution that comes to mind is to calculate a weighted average to correct the error. My question is, how do I determine the weights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on the characteristics of $f$.  Regardless, its average (by definition) is $\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{100}{f(x)dx}$, so your problem is one of estimating that integral from values at a discrete set of points.  For a highly discontinuous function you can use any [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum); for a differentiable function use the [Trapezoidal Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), for which you can estimate the error in terms of derivatives of $f$; for a thrice differentiable function use [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule), etc.  If necessary, you can combine the error estimates of these rules with statistical estimates of the error in computing each value of $f$ to obtain an estimate of the error in the average.

Comment: Sometimes I don't the forest for all the trees ... Thanks!