# Estimating 2D mean from uneven samples

Tags: sampling, error, mean

This CrossValidated post on [estimating mean from uneven samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-correct-uneven-sampling-distribution-when-calculating-the-mean) suggests using a (any) Riemann Sum to estimate the integral of an unevenly sampled 1D function.

To me the obvious extension to 2D is this:  given an uneven sample of f(x,y), create a triangulation of your sample points (x_i,y_i,z_i).  Estimate the integral by adding the volume under each triangle.

However, triangulating 3D points is not a trivial problem, so I imagine your results might depend on the quality of your triangulation.  Is there a better/simpler way of creating a piecewise planar approximation to a 2D surface if not in general, at least for the purpose of computing the integral?

Comment: In writing "3D points" were you contemplating an extension of this question to functions $f(x,y,z)$?  If not, then it seems you are still talking exclusively about 2D triangulations.  The potential confusion here is that the triangulation necessary for estimating $f(x,y)$ doesn't need to know anything about the sampled values (your $z_i$); it's a purely 2D problem.

Comment: I am not contemplating functions f(x,y,z).  When I said "triangulating 3D points" its because I assumed that a proper approximation of the surface f(x,y) is a triangulation of the 3D points (x_i, y_i, f(x_i,y_i)).  My comments implied my belief that the z-values are needed for the best piece-wise planar approximation to the surface.  I do believe that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I guess another way of asking my question is: for the 2D version of the linked question, is there a best/standard/accepted way of partitioning the domain over which you want to integrate?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  There are indeed standard ways to triangulate planar regions, such as a constrained Delaunay triangulation, but in some cases such triangulation can still lead to inferior (or biased) estimates of the mean of $f$.  To obtain really appropriate answers, please tell us a little about why and how the uneven sampling has occurred.

Comment: I have a laser range finder imaging a target shape.  The points on the target closer to the sensor are more densely sampled than the points farther away.  We want to estimate the center of the target by the mean of the points.

Comment: That is very helpful.  To craft a good response, one needs to know more precisely about the relationship between the target's "center" and its shape.  How are those related, exactly? E.g., is the center the closest point?  An identifiable spot on the target?  The centroid of the projection of the target's image onto the field of view?

Comment: The target is a planar circle of known size, but unknown position relative to the sensor.  We get measured ranges at different angles from the sensor's origin.  We segment the points into those on vs. off the target.  We estimate the normal of the target plane using the eigenvectors of the covariance of the sample points.  If our points were evenly sampled from the surface of the circle, we could estimate the center of the circle by the average of the sample points, but due to the geometry of how samples are collected, the points are unevenly distributed on the face of the circle.

Comment: Thanks for humoring me.  You have great information, but one more thing: do you have a reason for why the nearest points are sampled more densely?  Is it perhaps that the sampling intensity is proportional to the solid angle subtended?  A good characterization of this would lead to some simple accurate solutions, I believe.

Comment: Yes, our measurements are taken at regular angular intervals about two axes.  In euclidean coordinates this means that things closer to the sensor and closer to the center of rotation get sampled more densely.